# Oracle 11g database datafile addition to ASM without '+' sign

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-rac

what will happen, if we miss the '+' sign while adding datafile to ASM in oracle 11g database? Whether datafile added will be ASM based or Non-ASM based?

Comment: Non-ASM based. It will try to create the datafile in a default location (in db_create_file parameter, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @Ronato Afonso Thanks for the suggestion..but what happens if the db_create_file value in my database is empty?

Comment: Show me the DDL script.

Comment: alter tablespace CWSC add datafile 'DATA' size 100M AUTOEXTEND ON;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you miss the '+' sign, there will be several scenarios:

1. **db_create_file_dest is set and points to ASM (i.e: +DATA):**
   The database will take 'DATA' as an alias and will create ASM file on the destination associated with the 'DATA' alias that will be located at the ASM +DATA root directory.
2. **db_create_file_dest is set and points to filesystem:**
   It should be quite obvious that you'll have a new 'DATA' file in the location pointed at the parameter.
3. **db_create_file_dest is not set (worst scenario):**
   The database will default to $ORACLE_HOME/dbs and create a datafile there with the name 'DATA'.

A final piece of advice: Set the **db_create_file_dest** to point to the ASM DATA disk group and remove the datafile name parameter from your command:

**alter tablespace CWSC add datafile size 100M AUTOEXTEND ON;**

As you may know, even if you give a name to the datafile, when it's created on ASM, that name becomes an alias and the real filename is set by the ASM instance itself.

I hope this info helps you.